# Pseudo random number generation in compute shader

Tags: random, gpu, compute-shader

Using a C# script in Unity3D to control a HLSL compute shader, I'm trying to generate pseudo random numbers on the gpu. Following along with
[GPU Gems 3 Hybrid Tausworthe method](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch37.html)
and another thread [Pseudo Random Number Generation on the GPU](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337782/pseudo-random-number-generation-on-the-gpu#answers-header), I've come across an issue.

#### The problem:

the resulting texture appears to be one solid color. If I run the shader multiple times, I get a different solid color texture result every time, but the entire texture is the one color.

#### Compute shader code

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

RWTexture2D<float4> result; // 256 resolution texture to write to
uint4 randSeed;  //four uniform random numbers generated in C# script

struct RandomResult
{
    uint4 state;
    float value;
};

uint TausStep(uint z, int S1, int S2, int S3, uint M)
{
    uint b = (((z << S1) ^ z) >> S2);
    return ((z & M) << S3) ^ b;
}
uint LCGStep(uint z, uint A, uint C)
{
    return A * z + C;
}
RandomResult HybridTaus(uint4 state)
{
    state.x = TausStep(state.x, 13, 19, 12, 4294967294);
    state.y = TausStep(state.y, 2, 25, 4, 4294967288);
    state.z = TausStep(state.z, 3, 11, 17, 4294967280);
    state.w = LCGStep(state.w, 1664525, 1013904223);

    RandomResult rand;
    rand.state = state;
    rand.value = 2.3283064365387e-10 * (state.x ^ state.y ^ state.z ^ state.w);

    return rand;
}

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id)
{
    result[id.xy] = HybridTaus(randSeed).value;
}
```

Do I need to save the state on the gpu? If so, how would I do that? Do I need to deallocate the memory afterwards?

I did try to assign the result of the HybridTaus() function to randSeed in hopes that it would use the new value in the following HybridTaus(randSeed) call, like this:

```
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id)
{
    RandomResult rand = HybridTaus(randSeed);
    randSeed = rand.state;  // re-assign randSeed with the new state

    result[id.xy] = rand.value;
}
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider that one GPGPU invocation executes all `CSMain` in parallel, conceptually all at the same time.

So every pixel in your texture will come back with the same pseudo-random result as nothing changes in the values fed to the RNG.

Changing the seed value in the computer shader does not work: this is input-only and all `CSMain` **execute in parallel** so they all start with the same value. By the time the seed is changed it's too late. They are not sequentially executed.

To get "random" values in a shader you have to use some math formula and/or lookup texture both depending on the invocation coordinates (`id.xy`)

For example:

```
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id)
{
    uint4 rs = randSeed;
    rs.x += id.x;
    rs.y += id.y;
    rs.z += (uint)(sin(id.x * 71.01) * 500461564);
    rs.w += (uint)(cos(id.y * 53.7) * 1023467329);
    result[id.xy] = HybridTaus(rs).value;
}
```

Using far fractional bits of sine/cosine can work really well as long as your factors are not a small integer ratio of PI.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in `result[id.xy]` you must return a `float4` (RGBA) and the second values must be between 0 and 1

Also, you will randomly color not every pixel but every part of the pixels that belongs to a certain stream `id.xy`